# OpenGL [LWJGL3] - Matrix4x4 not rotating correctly

Tags: opengl, java, glsl, lwjgl

I tried today to make my own matrix4f class because of that LWJGL 3 does not include a class for it. So I arrived at rotation and it does not seem to work. I tried using the old util from LWJGL 2 and then it worked fine. Here's a screenshot of how it looks like.
[image]

[Here's a gif animation of how it looks.](http://giphy.com/gifs/1127CCJy2YcE12)
It's supposed to be a cube but as you can see it stretches when it rotates. Not only the x axis but the y and z axis to. 
Here's the code:

```
public Matrix4f rotate(Vector3f rotation) {
    Matrix4f xRotation = new Matrix4f();
    xRotation.setIdentity();

    float x = rotation.x;
    float y = rotation.y;
    float z = rotation.z;

    xRotation.m11 = (float) cos(x);
    xRotation.m21 = (float) -sin(x);

    xRotation.m12 = (float) sin(x);
    xRotation.m22 = (float) cos(x);

    Matrix4f yRotation = new Matrix4f();
    yRotation.setIdentity();

    yRotation.m00 = (float) cos(y);
    yRotation.m20 = (float) sin(y);

    yRotation.m02 = (float) -sin(y);
    yRotation.m22 = (float) cos(y);

    Matrix4f zRotation = new Matrix4f();
    zRotation.setIdentity();

    zRotation.m00 = (float) cos(z);
    zRotation.m10 = (float) -sin(z);

    zRotation.m01 = (float) -sin(z);
    zRotation.m11 = (float) cos(z);

    return multilpy(xRotation).multilpy(yRotation).multilpy(zRotation);
}
```

Can someone point the problem because I cannot find it.

Edit:
The multiplication and the projection code:

```
public Matrix4f multilpy(Matrix4f matrix) {
    // Row 0
    m00 = m00 * matrix.m00 + m10 * matrix.m01 + m20 * matrix.m02 + m30 * matrix.m03;
    m10 = m00 * matrix.m10 + m10 * matrix.m11 + m20 * matrix.m12 + m30 * matrix.m13;
    m20 = m00 * matrix.m20 + m10 * matrix.m21 + m20 * matrix.m22 + m30 * matrix.m23;
    m30 = m00 * matrix.m30 + m10 * matrix.m31 + m20 * matrix.m32 + m30 * matrix.m33;

    // Row 1
    m01 = m01 * matrix.m00 + m11 * matrix.m01 + m21 * matrix.m02 + m31 * matrix.m03;
    m11 = m01 * matrix.m10 + m11 * matrix.m11 + m21 * matrix.m12 + m31 * matrix.m13;
    m21 = m01 * matrix.m20 + m11 * matrix.m21 + m21 * matrix.m22 + m31 * matrix.m23;
    m31 = m01 * matrix.m30 + m11 * matrix.m31 + m21 * matrix.m32 + m31 * matrix.m33;

    // Row 2
    m02 = m02 * matrix.m00 + m12 * matrix.m01 + m22 * matrix.m02 + m32 * matrix.m03;
    m12 = m02 * matrix.m10 + m12 * matrix.m11 + m22 * matrix.m12 + m32 * matrix.m13;
    m22 = m02 * matrix.m20 + m12 * matrix.m21 + m22 * matrix.m22 + m32 * matrix.m23;
    m32 = m02 * matrix.m30 + m12 * matrix.m31 + m22 * matrix.m32 + m32 * matrix.m33;

    // Row 3
    m03 = m03 * matrix.m00 + m13 * matrix.m01 + m23 * matrix.m02 + m33 * matrix.m03;
    m13 = m03 * matrix.m10 + m13 * matrix.m11 + m23 * matrix.m12 + m33 * matrix.m13;
    m23 = m03 * matrix.m20 + m13 * matrix.m21 + m23 * matrix.m22 + m33 * matrix.m23;
    m33 = m03 * matrix.m30 + m13 * matrix.m31 + m23 * matrix.m32 + m33 *    matrix.m33;

    return this;
}

public static Matrix4f perspective(int width, int height, int fov, float zFar, float zNear) {
    Matrix4f matrix = new Matrix4f();

    float aspectRatio = (float) width / (float) height;
    float fovY = (float) ((1f / tan(Math.toRadians(fov / 2f))) * aspectRatio);
    float fovX = fovY / aspectRatio;
    float frustum_length = zFar - zNear;

    matrix.m00 = fovX;
    matrix.m11 = fovY;
    matrix.m22 = -((zFar + zNear) / frustum_length);
    matrix.m23 = -1;
    matrix.m32 = -((2 * zNear * zFar) / frustum_length);
    matrix.m33 = 0;

    return matrix;
}
```

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 400 core

in vec3 position;
in vec2 textureCoord;

out vec2 textureCoords;

uniform mat4 tranformation;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main(void) {

    gl_Position =  projection * tranformation * vec4(position,1.0);

    textureCoords = textureCoord;
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 400 core

in vec2 textureCoords;

out vec4 out_Color;

uniform sampler2D sampler;

void main(void) {
    vec4 color = texture(sampler, textureCoords);

    //if(color.a < 0.5) discard;

    out_Color = texture(sampler, textureCoords);
}
```

Comment: Why are there three `multilpy()` calls in the end?

Comment: @samhocevar so the rotation is applied to the matrix

Comment: Your code looks fine (at least the logic is correct); there may be a problem with other parts of your code. Maybe the multiplication part? Or where you compute the projection?

Comment: @samhocevar added the code for the projection and the multiplication

Comment: I hate this m00, m01, m02, m12, etc. approach to matrices. Arrays does exist

Comment: Can you show us your glsl code too?

Comment: An I'm also curious, why your ortographuc method returns a perslective projection matrix

Comment: @Bálint Yeah I was figuring out how orthographic worked but It first was perspective so I need to change that

Comment: If you're serious about game development you need to be using C++ or C#. With C# you can use OpenTK, which is a fantastic OpenGL wrapper(even Unity uses it). OpenTK comes with a Matrix4 struct and other useful items, like Quaternions, which you should be using for rotations.

Comment: Just the thought of a Matrix4 class instead of a struct makes me cringe. Your memory usage/garbage collector is going to be going crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your multiplication code. When you do:

```
m00 = m00 * matrix.m00 + m10 * matrix.m01 + m20 * matrix.m02 + m30 * matrix.m03;
```

You change `m00`, so you are not allowed to reuse it later in that function. Same for `m01` and all the other ones. Use temporary values instead:

```
float temp_m00 = m00 * matrix.m00 + m10 * matrix.m01 + m20 * matrix.m02 + m30 * matrix.m03;
```

Also, as suggested in the comments, try to use arrays instead of the `m00` `m01` etc. notation; you will have much shorter code and it will be easier to debug.

Comment: Do I have to use this at only m00 or multiple?

Comment: @Daan Meljer on each

Comment: @DaanMeijer the fact that you ask this question means that writing a correct matrix class is going to be a challenging task for you. If you wish to carry on, I highly recommend that you use unit tests all along, for instance with [JUnit](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_test_framework.htm).

Comment: @samhocevar Ill check it out, and yes indeed I just started with matrix math, do you have a good tutorial on matrix math? Btw thanks for helping me.

Comment: @samhocevar I have a question. what is the matrix field supposed to be(`matrix.m00`)? Is it all the rotations matrices multiplied together or something else?

Comment: @DaanMeijer I often recommend [this book](http://www.amazon.com/dp/1435458869). There are probably online versions of it, too.

Answer (score 0):

Your z rotation is messed up, it should be negative at (0; 1), and positive at  (1; 0)

[image: rotation matrix]

Comment: I changed that part of the code and it seems a bit better but its still streching here's how it looks: http://giphy.com/gifs/1127CCJy2YcE12